# how to use ArrayAdapter whan i have data in arraylist and use listView

Tags: listview, arraylist

How to use ArrayAdapter whan I have data in arraylist and use listView?

```
//String s = var_arrayList.get(3).getTitle().toString();//var_arrayList <= arrayList
    //R.layout.list_last_topic //<= listViwe have TextView - TextView - ImageView
    adapter = new new_topicAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_last_topic, new_topicList);
```

What should I write inside the class{new_topicAdapter}?